# Multi-scaled subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have 3 subplots and wish to plot temperature and rainfall on each subplot.  The temp scale is [-5,110] and the rain scale is [0, 2]. I want the rain data to use the full height of the subplot for display.

If I have a single plot, I can use twinx to create a 2nd scale. How can I achieve the same effect with multiple subplots?

Comment: Can you show us the current output?

Comment: You use `twinx` multiple times.

Comment: Using twinx multiple times seems to display what I want, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using sharey in True, if you create your plots like this:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(rows, cols, sharey=False)
```

You don't have any sharing problems with your Y axis.